# javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal address in string ``''

Tags: java, email

i m new here..

i m trying to send username and password to user's email id but it showing me an error about address which i have checked but its correct.

here is my emailutility code:

```
      Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
    InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setText(message);
```

and this is my emailsending servlet code:

```
     Logic.EmailUtility.sendEmail(host, port, user, pass, email, subject,
                message);
        resultMessage = "The username and password has been sent           successfully";

                    connection con = new connection();
                    con.getConnection();

                    String query = "insert into users (usertype,en_no,password) values(?,?,?)";
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.getConnection().prepareStatement(query) ;
```

and showing me the following error:

```
   javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal address in string ``''
at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.<init>(InternetAddress.java:110)
at Logic.EmailUtility.sendEmail(EmailUtility.java:50)
at Servlet.EmailSendingServlet.doPost(EmailSendingServlet.java:110)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was making a mistake in giving the address .

i was using two objects and i left blank for another `object`.

this was my one `object`.check the updated

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
msg.setText(message);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your toAddress or username ('from' address), or both, is an empty string.  You need to use a real email address there.   Look at the value used in line 50  of EmailUtility.java and make sure it is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

In my case when I got this error, I had `cc` mail address left blank in server.properties file. So, make sure addresses values exists and they're valid.

Answer (score 0):

Is the smtp host set up? I got this error when I had forgotten to set one in my configuration

Comment: yes. but this is very old question and i have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. In my case issue was with empty email address. So it was not null, but just empty string with length=0.
I've added additional validation to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

In my case there is wrongly enterd cc mail id which cause this roblem.